# Dll QT can use only POD?

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I am thinking about the files used in QT. Dlls should be written so that their interfaces do not use STL and any other libraries, but only (actually best) built-in types, right? So how can Qt can use own types in their library?

Comment: MS VC was lacking something like an ABI (application binary interface) for long time. (I'm not sure if they are about to change this in new compilers.) This resulted in that code compiled with different versions of MS VC was not compatible. The only exception were C APIs which limits you to POD types. Beyond this, it's no problem to built C++ applications with multiple DLLs as long as you ensure that all DLLs are built with the same version of MS VC. You can require that DLLs are used with a specific version of MS VC to overcome the POD restriction. (I saw this e.g. in gtkmm.)

Comment: I am just curious, where this requirement comes from: `...Dlls should be written so that their interfaces do not use STL and any other libraries...`?

Comment: I made a simple DLL with a parser like class (and create/delete functions to manage this class). This class had a function which take a vector of uint8_t. When i pass to this object vector, dll get totally weird data. When i made a function with pointer and size of that elements, everything works